# Why am I getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'now' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar, state

Why am I getting this error?

relevant code:

```
this.state = {
    now: 0
}


setInterval(function () {
    this.setState({ now: this.state.now + 1});
}, 100);
```

I am trying to increment now in order to update a ProgressBar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing state value by one using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364838/incrementing-state-value-by-one-using-react)

Comment: Execution context is different within the `setInterval` callback than where it was declared. You'll need to bind a function, create a closure, or use an arrow function. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for a little more information about execution context.

Comment: `setInterval(() => this.setState({ now: this.state.now + 1}), 100);`

Comment: @Tholle that worked! If you want to submit as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when you reference 'this' inside the function, this is the function itself not the context outside.
If you are using ecmascript you can use an arrow function

```
this.state = {
    now: 0
}

setInterval(() =>{
    this.setState({ now: this.state.now + 1});
}, 100);
```

with an arrow function 'this' have a different meaning.

or you can create a reference outside your context, like this.

```
this.state = {
    now: 0
}

let self = this;

setInterval(function () {
    self.setState({ now: self.state.now + 1});
}, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably when interval function runs 'this' doesn't means the same as when setInteval was called

You might try something like this

```
this.state = {
    now: 0
}

let that = this 

setInterval(function () {
    that.setState({ now: that.state.now + 1});
}, 100);
```